# Haskell Data.Yaml UTF-8 decoding

Tags: haskell, utf-8, yaml

I'm trying to decode a yaml file that contains UTF-8 strings, using Data.Yaml .  It chokes on the UTF-8.  I have narrowed down the example to this:

```
λ> :m + Data.ByteString
λ> :m + Data.Yaml
λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings 
λ> :set -XScopedTypeVariables 
λ> :set -XTypeApplications 
λ> let t :: ByteString  = "α"
λ> t
"\177"
λ> decodeEither' @Value t
Left (InvalidYaml (Just (YamlParseException {yamlProblem = "invalid leading UTF-8 octet", yamlContext = "", yamlProblemMark = YamlMark {yamlIndex = 0, yamlLine = 0, yamlColumn = 0}})))
```

I have tried different ByteStrings (Char8,UTF8 from the `utf8-string` package), but with the same result.

My locale is set to UTF8:

```
$ env | grep LANG
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: I am not very familiar with string handling in Haskell, particularly, how the `Show` instance for `ByteString` works, but `"\177"` does indeed not look like a legal UTF-8 multi-octet sequence, so the error from the decoder is correct.

Comment: The UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character [`α` U+03B1 *Greek small letter alpha*](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=03B1) is [`\xCE\xB1`](https://mothereff.in/utf-8#α).

Comment: Agreed, on further investigation, it appears to be something funny with the way that literal bytestrings involving UTF-8 are handled; they seem to be ASCII rather than UTF-8.  Or something.

Comment: @user3416536 Instead of creating the `ByteString` directly, try creating a `Text` from the "text" package and then apply `Data.Text.Encoding.encodeUtf8` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:encodeUtf8

Comment: I suspect that `let t :: ByteString  = "α"` doesn't do what you want it to do. Take a look at the relevant `IsString` instance!

Comment: See https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/issues/140.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in your example, the byte string is a truncated version of the initial ordinary string. The Greek lower case letter  "α" is Unicode character #945, and it appears as just code 177, while we have 945 == (3*256) + 177.

```
 λ> 
 λ> :m Data.Char
 λ> :m + Data.ByteString
 λ> :set -XScopedTypeVariables 
 λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings 
 λ> 
 λ> Prelude.map ord "Aα"
 [65,945]
 λ> 
 λ> 177 + (3*256)
 945
 λ> 
 λ> let t1 :: ByteString  = "α"
 λ> 
 λ> :t t1
 t1 :: ByteString
 λ> t1
 "\177"
 λ> Data.ByteString.length t1
 1
 λ>
```

The root cause might be that the UTF8 style of encoding has no special privileges. Hence the need to be quite explicit about the sort of conversion to byte string that you expect:

```
 λ> import Data.ByteString.UTF8 as BSUTF8
 λ> 
 λ> t2  = BSUTF8.fromString "α"
 λ> 
 λ> :t t2
 t2 :: ByteString
 λ> 
 λ> t2
 "\206\177"
 λ> 
 λ> Data.ByteString.length t2
 2
 λ> 
 λ> Prelude.putStrLn $ BSUTF8.toString t2
 α
 λ> 
 λ> :set -XTypeApplications
 λ> 
 λ> :m +Data.Yaml
 λ> 
 λ> Data.Yaml.decodeEither' @String  t2
 Right "\945"
 λ>
```

Comment: got it, and indeed, as @sjakobi said, the IsString instance isn't doing what I wanted here. Thanks!